# SSRS 2008 Charts: Selective Filtering on Charts within a chart

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have 3 Chart Series A,B,C of Data on single Chart

Normally When I apply filter on single series,the filter takes affect on all 3 series A,B,C .What I need is someway to apply particular filter on Series A,B but not C
like i have billable status as billable, non billable and partial billable.
i want two columns in the chart. 1 depicting only non billable employees and 1 showing the total of all billable status i.e., the whole team size.
my category axis has month.

i am not able to apply selective filters for one column of the two that i require.
please help.

Comment: Can you give more detail? How does your dataset look like and what exactly to you want to display on the chart and can you put a printscreen of the chart?

Comment: my dataset is simple "select * from table" query.

Comment: That's the query, I need an example of the data, to try to understand what you're talking about.

Comment: my table contains say ssn# and their billable status in the company
like
ssn  billable status
1    billable
2    non billable
3    partial billable
4    billable
Now i want a chart categorised on months with 1 column depicting total employee count and one column with employees' billable status= 'billable'.
can i do that without altering the query for my dataset and just apply selectiove filtering on series data inside the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to do what you want, because each series/category is a subset of your dataset, meaning that if you group by "all" then all elements of your data set will fall into that category.

The best way to achieve what you want is on the query that creates the dataset do a Union with the total of employees, something like:

```
SELECT 1 as NumberEmployees, SSN, BillableStatus FROM mytable
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), 0 as SSN, -1 as BillableStatus FROM mytable
```

Then when you'll have a status -1 that corresponds to all employees, and will appear on the chart as a different bar